# Drools - Fire multiple rules from multiple DRL files with different facts

Tags: java, drools

Drools - How can I fire multiple rules from multiple DRL files with different facts?

I'm new to Drools. I have multiple facts, each associated with different DRL files. How do I fire all the rules with different facts from a single java class or from a single session? Is it possible? Or should have different facthandles loaded into different sessions from different java classes to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also modify the kmodule.xml to include the resources (drl or xls files) you want in the kbase property. The attribute you should set is

`<kbase name = "Foo" packages="resource_package1, resource_package2,...,resource_packagen"/>`.

You can also set it to `all` meaning you will include all your project's resources. By creating a session and fire it all your rules with fire and run according to their salience.

Answer (score 1):

Add all your DRL files into a PackageBuilder and create a single KnowledgeBase with the resulting packages. Then create a session from that kbase and insert all your facts.

--Edit: adding code snippet

```
//Add all your drls to a single kbuilder
kbuilder.add(xxx.drl);
kbuilder.add(yyy.drl);
kbuilder.add(zzz.drl);

//Create a kbase using the generated kpackages
kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());

//Create a session containing all the rules you have in all your .drl files
StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

//Insert all your objects
ksession.insert(new XXX());
ksession.insert(new YYY());
ksession.insert(new ZZZ());

//fire all the activated rules
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: But how does it know which FACTS are associated with which RULES/.drl file?

Comment: And why would you like to know that? What is your use case?

Comment: Each drl file accepts a java object(fact) and evaluates the rules by passing the appropriate facthandle to the session and calling session.fireallrules(). If i package all the drl files into one package builder, how do i pass all the necessary facts(different java classes) to the session? A code snippet would be great...